# TypeError: Error while checking if the values in a list existed in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code as follows:

```
class SifFile():
    setting = {}
    interesting_param = ['Temp', 'Pressure']

    def __init__(self, get_param):
        self.File_Type = "Andor Technology Multi-Channel File"
        for k, v in get_param.items():            
            if SifFile.interesting_param in k:
                SifFile.setting[k] = v
                return SifFile.setting

get_parameter = {'Temp':75, 'Pressure':50, 'Helium':90, 'Exp':96}

sif = SifFile(get_parameter)
```

There is a big `dict` named `get_parameter` that has a few parameters and their values.

There is also a list named `interesting_param` that contains 2 elements.

What I want to do is to check which parameters from `interesting_param` list are present in the `get_parameter` dictionary and I want to save those parameters in an empty dict named `setting`

I tried running the above code, but it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 16, in 
>       sif = SifFile(get_parameter)
>
> File "", line 8, in **init**
>       if SifFile.interesting_param in k:
>
> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

**Expected output:**

```
setting = {'Temp':75, 'Pressure':50}
```

Comment: you have SifFile.interesting_param in k , but want k in SifFile.interesting_param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will give you the expected answer:

```
class SifFile():
    setting = {}
    interesting_param = ['Temp', 'Pressure']

    def __init__(self):
        self.File_Type = "Andor Technology Multi-Channel File"
        return


    def func(self, get_param):
        for k, v in get_param.items():
            if k in SifFile.interesting_param:
                SifFile.setting[k] = v

        return SifFile.setting

get_parameter = {'Temp':75, 'Pressure':50, 'Helium':90, 'Exp':96}

sif = SifFile()

x=sif.func(get_parameter)

print(x)
```

I have created anothter funcion called "func" because "**init**()" cannot return a dictionary. It should only return "None". 
Besides that, the condition statement within the for loop is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what's wrong: you are trying to check if a `key` exists in a `dict` but the `key` that you're checking for isn't a `string`. Let's look at the line in question:

```
if SifFile.interesting_param in k:
```

The error thinks that `SifFile.interesting_param` is a `list`, so let's have a look at where you define that:

```
interesting_param = ['Temp', 'Pressure']
```

Oh yeah, that *is* a `list`. Since a `list` can't be a `dict` key it throws an error.

You need to loop through your items in `interesting_param` one by one to check whether they're in the `dict`. I've implemented that here, along with a range of other issues in your code, mainly surrounding how you'd implemented the class:

```py
class SifFile():
    """
    Class for holding and processing sif files.
    """
    def __init__(self, params):
        """
        Define the variables you want to use in your class
        """
        self.file_type = "Andor Technology Multi-Channel File"
        self.interesting_params = ['Temp', 'Pressure']
        self.given_params = params
        self.setting = {}

    def get_settings(self):
        """
        Return list of settings of interest
        """
        # Look at every parameter of interest in turn
        for param in self.interesting_params:
            # Check to see if it is in the dict of given parameters
            if param in self.given_params:
                # If it is then add it to the setting dict
                self.setting[param] = self.given_params[param]

        # Return the setting dict once the loop is done
        return self.setting


parameters = {'Temp':75, 'Pressure':50, 'Helium':90, 'Exp':96}
sif = SifFile(parameters)
print(sif.get_settings())
```

Note that your variables are now all [instance variables rather than class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) (they start with `self`) because you're changing them, so they are unlikely to be the same for every class.

Comment: `Since a list can't be a dict key it throws an error` actually it's checking whether the list is in the _key_ `k`.  A list cannot be part of a string, hence the `TypeError`.  If the OP was checking whether the list was a key in the dict they'd get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`